# ¿Por qué la velocidad de la bola no es constante; y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: python

He probado con varios entornos de desarrollo (VisualStudio, Anaconda); pero el movimiento de la bola es inconstante, con acelerones aleatorios; especialmente cuando se mueven las palas.
¿Podéis confirmarme si a vosotros os pasa lo mismo y, en ese caso, cómo solucionarlo?

```
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800,height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

pad=turtle.Turtle()
pad.speed(0)
pad.shape("square")
pad.color("Blue")
pad.penup()
pad.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
pad.goto(-350,0)

pada=turtle.Turtle()
pada.speed(0)
pada.penup()
pada.shape("square")
pada.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
pada.goto(350,0)
pada.color("red")

ball=turtle.Turtle()
ball.penup()
ball.color("white")
ball.shape("circle")
ball.speed(0)
ball.color("white")
ball.dx=0.2
ball.dy=0.2

#Function movement
def padup():
    y=pad.ycor()
    y+=20
    pad.sety(y)
def paddown():
    y=pad.ycor()
    y-=20
    pad.sety(y)

def padaup():
    y=pada.ycor()
    y+=20
    pada.sety(y)

def padadown():
    y=pada.ycor()
    y-=20
    pada.sety(y)

#Keyboard feedback
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(padup, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddown, "s")
wn.onkeypress(padaup, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(padadown, "Down")

#Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    #Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor()+ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor()+ball.dy)

    #Border checking
    if ball.ycor()>290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy*=-1

    if ball.ycor()<-290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy*=-1

    if ball.xcor()>390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx*=-1

    if ball.xcor()<-390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx*=-1

    if pad.ycor()>250:
        pad.sety(250)

    if pada.ycor()>250:
        pada.sety(250)

    if pad.ycor()<-250:
        pad.sety(-250)

    if pada.ycor()<-250:
        pada.sety(-250)

    #Collision
    if (ball.xcor()>340 and ball.xcor()<350) and (ball.ycor()<pada.ycor()+60 and ball.ycor()>pada.ycor()-60):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx*=-1

    if (ball.xcor()<-340 and ball.xcor()>-350) and (ball.ycor()<pad.ycor()+60 and ball.ycor()>pad.ycor()-60):
        ball.dx*=-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer es un problema de rendimiento en CPU,aunque exactamente no conozco las causas principales  pero si puedes darse una solución. Puedes utilizar un `sleep` para dormir un determinado tiempo por cada movimiento así e llevara mejor el control del movimiento constante de la bola.

```
while True:
    wn.update()
    #Tiempo a dormir para cada movimiento actualizado
    time.sleep(1/1000)
    #Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx*5)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy*5)
```

Comment: Genial; solucionado. Me dio problemas al principio porque desconocía que time era un módulo; pero una vez importado y recalibrado el movimiento de la bola va como la seda. Muchas gracias!
PS: Respecto a que el problema esté en la CPU me sorprende ya que es un i7 de 9ª generación.

Comment: Ah si lo siento me olvide colocar la importacion de time pero  lo bueno es que lo descubriste :) si te sirvio la respuestas no olvides calificarla como respondida Saludos.

Comment: Respecto a lo. del rendimiento, eh leido por ahi, que puede ser al repintado innecesario de los cuadros por segundo que realiza al moverse pero nada es 100% preciso.